# Query to Secondary on Sharded Cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

How to specify query from mongos shell which is inteded to query data from secondary?

The goal is not to bother primary load on write and use data in secondary shards instead.

Comment: There is no term "secondary shards". A shard most of the times uses a replica set which is PRI-SEC-SEC.

Comment: thanks for the correction, I mean secondary of shard replica set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1) The safest is to use on your driver the "secondary" option as described on the below article:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/

2) Another option is to tag your secondaries as described below and target your queries against the tag, most drivers offer that option.

Disadvantage is that you have to ensure that these nodes can't become primaries else you will target primaries. Advantage is that you can target certain operations to certain nodes.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/#add-tag-sets-to-a-replica-set

I would say to stick with first option if you just starting using mongo.

Comment: i see. so this is actually same with a normal (non-sharded) replica set. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a cursor, you'll want to call readPref('secondary') on it.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.readPref/#cursor.readPref

And I think you mean replica instead of shard.

Comment: i mean replica set which a shard in sharded cluster. so it is a secondary of shard replica set